# Add dependency for executing main method during maven package

Tags: java, maven

I configured maven to call main method during maven package:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>arg1</argument>
                        <argument>arg2</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

`org.jsoup` dependency is necessary to execute my main method but I don't want to set `compile` scope for it. How to add this dependency only for execution my main class? I tried several ways but I failed.

**====EDIT====**

I don't want to set `compile` scope because I don't want `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy it to dependency directory. 
I have just realized that I can set `compile` scope and add exclusion to maven-dependency-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeGroupIds>org.jsoup</excludeGroupIds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Why you don't want to set compile scope ?

Comment: So after reading your edit, where will the "required" dependency will be located ? If it's provided in the environment classpath, scope should be "provided"

Comment: `provided` scope does not work, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/nodes/Node`. Finally I set `compile` scope.

Comment: Is this still an open question or is your edit revealing that you have figured out your original question?

Comment: I resolved my issue by adding `excludeGroupIds` to `maven-dependency-plugin` (as I wrote in my EDIT) but I am still curious If is it possible to add dependency only for `exec-maven-plugin` plugin. I would like to set `provided` scope for `org.jsoup` and add it to `classpath` only for `exec-maven-plugin` execution.